# Checklist for registering patent

Tags: new-patent, patent-registration-steps

I am surely not having experience with patents but I want to know if there is any site or application that can assist me get patent registered in European market (and have all steps/prerequisites given in **checklist based to track my progress**).

If this question should not belong here, please write in comment to delete question or suggest correct place (if possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might find a checklist to help you with submitting a properly formatted application with all required components (Description, Drawings, Claim, Abstract). You can also find guides to the phases the application goes through (filing, requesting substantive examination, rejection, arguments/amendments, acceptance, opposition period, granting and validating in one or more specific countries). However, drafting a quality application that will ultimately be accepted is a very specialized task. Prepare for a long period of self-education, use of a professional, or possibly ultimate frustration.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ressources on the website of the European Patent Office (EPO). For example [this site about the basics of applying for a european patent](https://www.epo.org/applying/basics.html) aims at beginners.

Note however art. [133 EPC](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2016/e/ar133.html):

> (2)
>   Natural or legal persons not having their residence or principal place of business in a Contracting State shall be represented by a professional representative and act through him in all proceedings established by this Convention, other than in filing a European patent application; the Implementing Regulations may permit other exceptions.

If you are no resident of a contracting state, you can only file the patent application and pay the relevant fees associated with the filing and need an attorney for everything else.